# Difference between "ermutigen" and "unterstützen"?

Tags: difference, verb

I find these words similar, but I need clarification on their differences in usage.

Comment: Where are you from, what dictionaries did you try? Checking an English/German dictionary I myself find the difference apparent. So what exactly confuses you? :)

Comment: They give "encourage" for unterstützen, but not at first.

Comment: If you don't specify what confuses you and why, you'll likely only get the dictionary explanation from us as well, as we have to guess

Comment: Mut = courage, jemand *er*mutigen = to *en*courage someone (i.e., to arouse or elicit someone's courage). Jemand unterstützen = to back/ support/ endorse someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both could be translated as 'to support' or 'to encourage'. I gather *ermutigen* is in more the sense of emotional encouragement, as in to comfort, while *unterstützen* implies something more tangible, as in to aid or promote. You might want to bookmark dict.cc since imo it's a great resource for figuring out these subtle differences. It usually give a variety of different translations so you get an idea of the scope of possible meanings.

Comment: Without additional info from OP, I find this answer very counterproductive.

Comment: That is what I asked for, thank you.